# Show that for every real number x, there exists an integer n so that $\ \left|n\ -x\right|\ \le\ \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, real-numbers

I am very new to proofs and just wanted to make sure that mine isn't absolute nonsense. Here's the question and what I wrote:

> Show that for every real number x, there exists an integer n so that
>   $\ \left|n\ -x\right|\ \le\ \frac{1}{2}$

Both sides of the expression are positive, so we can square them without changing the inequality:
$${\left|n\ -\ x\right|\ }^2\le\ \frac{1}{4}$$
We get a quadratic inequality in terms of n and solve for the n intercepts:
$$4{(n\ -\ x)\ }^2\le\ 1$$
$$4{(n}^2-\ 2xn\ +\ x^2)\ -1\le\ 0$$
$$n^2-\ 2xn\ +\ x^2\ -\ \frac{1}{4}\ =\ 0$$
$$n=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{{(-2x)}^2-4\left(x^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)\ }}{2}\ =\ \frac{2x\ \pm\ 1}{2}$$

Testing the value of the expression for n values between the two intercepts:
$$n\in\left(-\infty,\ \frac{2x-1}{2}\right):\ \ \left(x-1\right)^2\ -\ 2x(x-1)\ +\ x^2\ -\frac{1}{4\ }\ =\ (2x^2\ +\ \frac{3}{4}\ )\ >\ 0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\ \  $$
$$n\in\left(\ \frac{2x-1}{2},\ \frac{2x+1}{2}\right):\ \ {(x)}^2\ -\ 2x(x)\ +\ x^2\ -\frac{1}{4\ }\ =\ -\ \frac{1}{4}\ <\ 0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\ \ $$ 
$$n\in\left(\ \frac{2x+1}{2},\ \infty\right):\ \ \left(x\ +1\right)^2\ -\ 2x(x+1)\ +\ x^2\ -\frac{1}{4\ }\ =\ \ \frac{3}{4}\ \ >\ 0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Therefore, $ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \left|n\ -\ x\right|\ \le\ \frac{\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{2}} $   is true if   $ n\in\left(\ \frac{\mathbf{2}x-\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{2}},\ \frac{\mathbf{2}x+\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{2}}\right): $$

$$\frac{2x-1}{2}\ \le\ n\ \le\ \frac{2x+1}{2}$$
$$x-\frac{1}{2}\ \le\ n\ \le\ x+\frac{1}{2}\ $$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ \le\ n\ -x\ \le\ \frac{1}{2}\ $$
$$\ \left|n\ -x\right|\ \le\ \frac{1}{2}\ $$

Would that be a reasonable proof?
Also, how would I show a similar thing for complex numbers:

> $\ \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a set of complex numbers z = a +bi with a,b $
> > \in\mathbb{Z} $
>
> We define $ N(z)\ =\ \left|z\right|^2\ =\ z\bar{z}$
>
> Show that $\forall w\in\mathbb{C},\ \ \ \exists z\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$  so
>   that $ N(z\ – w) ≤ \frac{1}{2}\ .$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  It looks like you assume the theorem is true and then deduce, using that, that it is true.

Comment: Much simpler:  let $a$ be the greatest integer $≤x$ .  Then $a+1$ is the least integer $>x$.  But we can't have both $|a-x|$ and $|a+1-x|$ greater than $\frac 12$.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that finding a general formula for n in terms of x would be enough to prove that it's possible to find one for any x, which would make the theorem true; looks like I was wrong.

Comment: But you didn't find a general formula for $n$. You just found another way of stating the same condition on $n$ ( almost, that statement should be $n \in \left[\frac{2x-1}2,\frac{2x+1}2\right]$). But you didn't demonstrate that some *integer* satisfies this version of the condition, either. lulu's method does prove this, assuming one already knows that any set of integers bounded above has a greatest element.

Comment: Ah, now I see! Thank you so much, both of you. How would I formally write that we can’t have both $\left|a-x\right|\ $ and $\ \left|a+1-x\right|$ greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ then? Or is that statement enough on its own?

Comment: If $a \le x$ and $a+1 \gt x$ and $x-a>\frac 12$ and $a+1-x>\frac 12$ then $1>1$, a contradiction

Comment: Thank you! Much clearer now